# plasticscm ignore.conf file ignore particular folder

Tags: unity-game-engine, plasticscm

I have a library folder which is located under Assets/Core. So the full path is Assets/Core/Libaray i want to ignore. Means, it this paritcular libaray folder should be uploaded on server, and it should not be ignore. I have added these two line one by one to solve the problem. But it not solve my problem.
Assets/Core/Library
or
!Assets/Core/Library
Remember in my ignore.conf file the top two lines contain
Library
library
when i remove these two lines all the libaray files are showing correctly.

Comment: as you have not included your ignore file settings i can only guess you wrote "library" and so let it ignore all things called library, not /library, to only ignore the top level one.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Yes, you are right. I was not expecting that only "library" ignore from everywhere. It wokred for me. Can you please post the answer  with details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when the ignore file lists a word on its own such as "Library" and not "/Library" denoting the one at the top.  All files and folders matching that criteria will be ignored as per its instructions. Including Assets/Core/Library